# Unknown NGINX open socket alerts

Tags: nginx

I am new to Nginx. When I checked the error log I see this alerts going on for very long. Should I be concerned?

```
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #273 left in connection 178
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #275 left in connection 179
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *38654 open socket #118 left in connection 181
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *37932 open socket #279 left in connection 182
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *37935 open socket #281 left in connection 185
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #284 left in connection 187
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #286 left in connection 188
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *37940 open socket #289 left in connection 190
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *37941 open socket #290 left in connection 191
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *37945 open socket #291 left in connection 192
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #293 left in connection 194
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #295 left in connection 195
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *37947 open socket #297 left in connection 196
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *37951 open socket #304 left in connection 198
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #302 left in connection 200
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #300 left in connection 201
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *37965 open socket #309 left in connection 202
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #305 left in connection 204
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #328 left in connection 206
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #315 left in connection 211
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #318 left in connection 215
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #324 left in connection 216
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *38017 open socket #323 left in connection 217
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *0 open socket #124 left in connection 220
2015/09/24 15:13:57 [alert] 2416#0: *38082 open socket #333 left in connection 225
```

Comment: These are known as 'socket leaks'. What version of nginx are you using?

Comment: @LukePeterson its Nginx 1.6.1 on Amazon AMI

Comment: And my question is that the server was working fine for few month without any change but all the sudden Nginx cpu became 100% and server went down.